# Convert a column of Rows to only one column column in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query in SQL Server 2012 :

```
select 
    tblplantitle.id, tblplantoproductpayment.productid
from 
    tblplantitle 
inner join  
    tblplan on tblplan.plantitleid = tblplantitle.id
inner join 
    tblplantoproductpayment on tblplantoproductpayment.planid = tblplan.id
group by 
    tblplantitle.id, tblplantoproductpayment.productid
```

The result is like this :

```
id    productid
 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     10
 2     5
 2     1
 3     4
 3     11
```

but I want this result :

```
1    1,2,3,10
2    5,1
3    4,11
```

How can I get that result ?

Comment: do you hear about Pivot Table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH cte as 
(
select 
    tblplantitle.id, tblplantoproductpayment.productid
from 
    tblplantitle 
inner join  
    tblplan on tblplan.plantitleid = tblplantitle.id
inner join 
    tblplantoproductpayment on tblplantoproductpayment.planid = tblplan.id
group by 
    tblplantitle.id, tblplantoproductpayment.productid
)
SELECT id, productid = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + productid
           FROM cte b 
           WHERE b.id= a.id
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM cte a
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query for the desired output.

```
SELECT tblplantitle.id
      , STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(tblplantoproductpayment.productid AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
               FROM tblplantoproductpayment 
               WHERE tblplantoproductpayment.planid  = tblplan.id
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_ProductIds
FROM tblplantitle 
      INNER JOIN  tblplan on tblplan.plantitleid = tblplantitle.id
GROUP BY tblplantitle.id
```